# Python sockets sending unexpected RST packets

Tags: python, sockets

I have threaded Python 2.7.12 code that waits for connections from external devices, and then spins off a thread to work with each device.  80% of the time this works fine, but every once in a while I get unwanted RST from the OS or Python, I'm not sure which.

The TCP connection starts off normally and then abrubptly is reset.

SYN, SYN/ACK, ACK, RST

The server initiates the RST.  The timing is also extremely tight so I feel like this is probably Python's socket bugging out or the OS taking over for some reason.  How could I debug this?  Since I'm not seeing any errors in my Python code and logging itself, is there a ways to debug the sockets code directly used by Python?

Here is the code:

```
while True:
host = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
port = 3001
try:
    tcpsock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    tcpsock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
    tcpsock.bind((host,port))
    tcpsock.listen(5)
    print ("\nListening for incoming connections...")
    (clientsock, (ip, port)) = tcpsock.accept()
    newthread = ClientThread(ip, port, clientsock)
    newthread.start()
    threads = 0
    for t in threading.enumerate():
        threads += 1
    logger.info('######################## THREADS = %s' % (threads))
except Exception as e:
    logger.critical('Exception: %s.  Error initializing thread' % (e))
```

EDIT1 - Adding ClientThread code:

```
class ClientThread(threading.Thread):

def __init__(self,ip,port,clientsocket):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.ip = ip
    self.port = port
    self.csocket = clientsocket
```

The rest of the code just starts working with the device.

Comment: Hard to say without knowing what `ClientThread` does...

Comment: Some starting points: A RST means the socket is being closed. Python will close a socket if the object is garbage-collected…

Comment: Use UDP connection for unlimited data and buffer size. RST sometime rise for `BUFF_OWERFLOW`.  Never   bind a service on single port, incoming and outgoing can't use same ports. In your example accept from `port = 3001` push data to `(server)3002 >> 3001(client)` , but this sample work with single `client`, you need use second port if second client is connected, like : `(server)3003 >> 3001(client_2)`. **So you can't hear anything on your mouth and can't eat anything with your ear.**

Comment: Another tips : "Don't use any port without any testing(Already on use)"

Comment: I will take a look at bind testing before binding blindly, thanks.  As I understand it regarding the "single" port is that the moment a client connects it's spun off to another thread freeing up 3001 to keep listening.  Are you thinking maybe 3001 is being hit by too many clients?  If so, how do you combat that?  I can't tell the device to use a list of ports, only a single one.

Comment: **Some hosts have a hardware clock that is guaranteed to be
              monotonic between hardware resets.**  in [RFC1323](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1323.txt)

Comment: Is the server waiting for the threads to finish, or exiting immediately? I would expect the listening socket to be created *outside* of the loop ...

Answer (score 1):

The RST packet means "I don't have a connection open for the packet you just sent me". You're right, if you follow the simple examples on python.org, then Python will generate RST packets. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import socket, sys, time

# Create a TCP/IP socket
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)

# Bind the socket to the port
server_port = 10000
print 'starting up on port %s' % server_port
sock.bind(('', server_port))

# Listen for incoming connections
sock.listen(1)

print 'waiting for a connection'
conn, cli_addr = sock.accept()
print 'connection from', cli_addr
data = "Hello, World!\n" \
    + "Your IP is " + cli_addr[0] + "\n"
HTTP = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\nContent-Type: text/html\nContent-Length:"
conn.sendall(HTTP + str(len(data)) + "\n\n" + data);
conn.close()
```

`tcpdump` then says:

```
10:59:48.847443 IP 127.0.0.1.38330 > 127.0.0.1.10000: Flags [S], seq 1326297161, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 3126487416 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:59:48.847462 IP 127.0.0.1.10000 > 127.0.0.1.38330: Flags [S.], seq 1677934801, ack 1326297162, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 3126487416 ecr 3126487416,nop,wscale 7], length 0
10:59:48.847475 IP 127.0.0.1.38330 > 127.0.0.1.10000: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126487416 ecr 3126487416], length 0
10:59:48.847547 IP 127.0.0.1.38330 > 127.0.0.1.10000: Flags [P.], seq 1:80, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126487416 ecr 3126487416], length 79
10:59:48.847557 IP 127.0.0.1.10000 > 127.0.0.1.38330: Flags [.], ack 80, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126487416 ecr 3126487416], length 0
10:59:48.847767 IP 127.0.0.1.10000 > 127.0.0.1.38330: Flags [P.], seq 1:95, ack 80, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126487416 ecr 3126487416], length 94
10:59:48.847790 IP 127.0.0.1.38330 > 127.0.0.1.10000: Flags [.], ack 95, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126487416 ecr 3126487416], length 0
10:59:48.847861 IP 127.0.0.1.10000 > 127.0.0.1.38330: Flags [R.], seq 95, ack 80, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126487416 ecr 3126487416], length 0
10:59:48.847862 IP 127.0.0.1.38330 > 127.0.0.1.10000: Flags [F.], seq 80, ack 95, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126487416 ecr 3126487416], length 0
10:59:48.847878 IP 127.0.0.1.10000 > 127.0.0.1.38330: Flags [R], seq 1677934896, win 0, length 0
```

The problem is that `conn.close()` destroys the socket data structure, so the OS doesn't recognize the next packet. Notice that the client (`curl`) is sending a nice FIN packet, but the server (Python code above) is not.

To solve this, you need to send a FIN packet by calling `conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)` and then leave the socket structure around long enough to catch any straggling packets (you could do this in another thread). So instead of `conn.close()`, do:

```
conn.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
time.sleep(1)
conn.close()
```

With this change, both sides send FIN, and the RST are missing from `tcpdump`:

```
11:05:50.201352 IP 127.0.0.1.38338 > 127.0.0.1.10000: Flags [S], seq 4249130338, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 3126848770 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:05:50.201368 IP 127.0.0.1.10000 > 127.0.0.1.38338: Flags [S.], seq 1410528158, ack 4249130339, win 43690, options [mss 65495,sackOK,TS val 3126848770 ecr 3126848770,nop,wscale 7], length 0
11:05:50.201381 IP 127.0.0.1.38338 > 127.0.0.1.10000: Flags [.], ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126848770 ecr 3126848770], length 0
11:05:50.201441 IP 127.0.0.1.38338 > 127.0.0.1.10000: Flags [P.], seq 1:80, ack 1, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126848770 ecr 3126848770], length 79
11:05:50.201450 IP 127.0.0.1.10000 > 127.0.0.1.38338: Flags [.], ack 80, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126848770 ecr 3126848770], length 0
11:05:50.201568 IP 127.0.0.1.10000 > 127.0.0.1.38338: Flags [P.], seq 1:95, ack 80, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126848770 ecr 3126848770], length 94
11:05:50.201594 IP 127.0.0.1.38338 > 127.0.0.1.10000: Flags [.], ack 95, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126848770 ecr 3126848770], length 0
11:05:50.201643 IP 127.0.0.1.10000 > 127.0.0.1.38338: Flags [F.], seq 95, ack 80, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126848770 ecr 3126848770], length 0
11:05:50.201691 IP 127.0.0.1.38338 > 127.0.0.1.10000: Flags [F.], seq 80, ack 96, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126848770 ecr 3126848770], length 0
11:05:50.201707 IP 127.0.0.1.10000 > 127.0.0.1.38338: Flags [.], ack 81, win 342, options [nop,nop,TS val 3126848770 ecr 3126848770], length 0
```